# How to timestamp when a link opens in Google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am amature when it comes to google sheets or excel but I have a question(using Google sheets)

Is there a script or a way that I can do to a cell to do a timestamp (in column A) when a link or QR code gets opened (links are stored in column B)?

knowing that the link leads to an auto-responded Google Form

I really do not know if that is passable or not, can you please educate me about it thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Log the timestamp in a cell when a another cell clicked on google sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70895181/log-the-timestamp-in-a-cell-when-a-another-cell-clicked-on-google-sheet)

Comment: In your situation, in order to achieve your goal, is it required to access a link in a cell? I thought that the approach might be changed by this.

Comment: @LorenaGomez Thank you for the info, it is not what I am looking for but I think I can use that in another project thank you so much

Comment: @Tanaike Hi, no it is not required to access a link in a cell

Comment: Thank you for replying. In that case, how do you want to run the script for putting a timestamp? I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot imagine your expected situation.

Comment: @Tanaike no it's okay ^_^, 

My plan is to have sign-in and sign-out for users using a QR code, every time the user scans and opens the QR code it will generate a timestamp in the cell (in column A) next to the QR code (column B) for that user.

To be honest I am not sure if that is even possible but I think I need to find another method to do so.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, in that case, I thought that it might be required to run a script by accessing a link in a cell. How about this?

Comment: @Tanaike,  yeah I am thinking of the same thing now, I will try it, how to do that?

Comment: Thank you for replying. In that case, I think that Web Apps can be used. But, before Web Apps created by Google Apps Script is used, I have to know your actual situation. In your situation, the specific hyperlink in a cell has already been decided? If you can use Web Apps URL, this method can be used. How about this?

Comment: @Tanaike yeah, I think the web apps is my solution now. YES, the hyperlinks for the QR codes have already been decided.  Can you direct me to where I can do this method?

Thank you for your help and the effort to answer my question, I really do appreciate it.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `YES, the hyperlinks for the QR codes have already been decided.`, in this case, how do you want to feedback from the link? When Web Apps is used, how do you want to do your `hyperlinks for the QR codes`? If your link can be changed to Web Apps, I thought that your goal can be achieved. But, from your reply, in this case, I'm worried that Web Apps might not be able to be used. I apologize for my poor English skill. So, first, I have to correctly understand your expected situation. Can I ask you about the detail of your expected situation?

Comment: For example, if you want to make users open the link with the browser, I think that Web Apps cannot be used. I'm worried about this situation. So, I asked about your expected feedback from the link.